# Stack: Compile stand-alone source file

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Once you've installed Stack, you can use it to install GHC for you. Great!

...now how do I compile a file with it?

To be clear: What you're *supposed* to do is write a package specification and have Stack build that. But surely there must be a way to trivially compile a tiny helper file inside that project? It seems silly to have to construct an entire project just so I can build a tiny helper program and have it easily runnable from the shell.

I know I can *run* any Haskell file using Stack. But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to *compile* the thing...

Comment: Do you know about `stack script`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `stack ghc -- <file names>` to compile and link a set of files (it's briefly mentioned in [Stack's user guide](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#ghcrunghc)):

> You'll sometimes want to just compile (or run) a single Haskell source file, instead of creating an entire Cabal package for it. You can use `stack exec ghc` or `stack exec runghc` for that. As simple helpers, we also provide the **`stack ghc`** and `stack runghc` commands, for these common cases.

The `--` is to ensure the arguments we pass are sent to `ghc`, rather than being parsed as arguments to `stack exec`. It's the same thing as when trying to pass arguments to an executable you've made using the normal stack toolchain: `stack exec myExe -foo` passes `-foo` to `exec`, not `myExe`, `stack exec myExe -- -foo` behaves as desired.

---

For example:

Bar.hs

```
module Bar where

bar :: Int
bar = 5
```

Foo.hs

```
import Bar

main :: IO ()
main = print bar
```

Compilation (don't even need to specify `Bar.hs` in the build files, it's sourced automatically):

```
> stack ghc -- Foo.hs
[1 of 2] Compiling Bar              ( Bar.hs, Bar.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Foo.hs, Foo.o )
Linking Foo ...
> ./Foo
5
```

---

There's no problem with dependencies either - it looks like all the packages installed locally are available to the build (you can use `containers` or `QuickCheck` without any additional build params).

Comment: Is there a way to generate an executable using stack scripts? The stack wiki only shows how to run them.